# updated server to raring, php not working

Tags: server, 13.04, php

I updated a server to raring ring-tail, and most everything seems to work, except php5.
The ssh, apache, ICECAST and other functions are operational. I have tried purging the installation files, and reinstalling. This had no effect. 
http://omh.umeche.maine.edu/test.php

a page with phpinfo();
shows nothing. 
Im not sure where to go with it, can anyone help me get php5 working again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/php5.html)

then read / edited this file:

```
sudo vim  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf
```

commented out the lines:
 Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default

```
#To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.

<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_value engine Off
    </Directory></IfModule>
```

php seems to work now. Though I am curious, what are the pitfalls of having done this?